# Login with Basic Authentication in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm using In-Build template for Login and Registration in Web Api.

It uses Token based Authentication .

But what I want is to login a user I want use Basic authentication, after web api will return a token then now I want to use that to to call api methods.

right now I request for login like this

```
var resp = $http({
            url: "/TOKEN",
            method: "POST",
            data: $.param({ grant_type: 'password', username: userlogin.username, password: userlogin.password }),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        });
```

and It return me a token, which I send it with next request to call authorize methods.

But I wand to send username and password **:** separated like basic authentication

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

 string authInfo = "admin" + ":" + "123456";
 authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authInfo);

 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:63173/TOKEN");
```

And server side I will decode it back to get username and password to validate user and will return authentication token.

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
                credentials = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(credentials));

                int separator = credentials.IndexOf(':');
                string name = credentials.Substring(0, separator);
                string password = credentials.Substring(separator + 1);
```

But I don't know where to modify the existing code.

Comment: Server-side are you using `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth` and `app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround I can think of is writing a simple Owin middleware that remaps the credentials found in the Authorization header to form fields, executed at the beginning of the Owin pipeline.

Something similar to this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(async (ctx, n) =>
        {
            if (ctx.Request.Path == new PathString("/path/to/token")) //the same path you specified in the "TokenEndpointPath" property of "OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions"
            {
                var authHeader = ctx.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authHeader) && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic "))
                {
                    //parse here authHeader
                    var name = GetUsernameFromHeader(authHeader);
                    var password = GetPasswordFromHeader(authHeader);
                    //change the above lines with your parsing methods

                    var form = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
                    {
                        { "grant_type", new [] {"password" }},
                        { "username", new []{ name }},
                        { "password", new [] { password}}
                    };

                    ctx.Set<IFormCollection>("Microsoft.Owin.Form#collection", new FormCollection(form));
                }
            }

            await n.Invoke();
        });


        //app.UseWebApi... 
        //other middlewares
    }
}
```

I warn you that this approach just writes those values to the Owin context and will work as long as the underlying `OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware` implementation doesn't change.

Comment: But it gives null, When I try to access `context.ClientId` in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method. where as I have set this `StartUp` like this `{ "client_id", new [] { clientId}}` .
I'm also sending clientId in Basic Authentication.

Comment: I answered your question, which never mentioned the client_id. You cannot get the client_id from the context in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` if you do not parse and validate it first by providing `OnValidateClientAuthentication` property (e.g. using `TryGetFormCredentials` method on `OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext`).

Comment: Thank you very much . I figured out how to set ClientId. 
in `ValidateClientAuthentication` method `var getClient = context.Parameters["client_id"];  context.OwinContext.Set<string>("as:client_Id", clientId);
            context.Validated(clientId);`   
Not I can get `context.ClientId`